# Trying to "fix" navigation position on scroll

Tags: jquery, html, css, fixed

I'm trying to figure out how to get my navigation to stick to the top of the page when the window scrolls down. I've seen a few examples on how to do this (found one that worked, but made my menu's click function stop working) but I haven't been able to get it to work myself.

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q7jpvkty/1/)

**jQuery (code in question)**

```
 /* Code to "fix" navigation */
        $(window).scroll(function(){

        var menu = $("#navbar");
        var menuWidth = $("#wrapper").css("width");
        var menuPos = menu.offset();
        var menuTopPos = menuPos.top;

        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > (menuTopPos) ) {
            menu.css("position", "fixed").css("top", "0px").css("left", "0px").css("width", menuwidth);
        }
        else {
            menu.css("position", "relative").css("width", "100%");
        }

    });
```

**HTML (basic structure)**

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="header">
(Header stuff goes here)
</div>

<div id="navbar>
<ul class="nav-tabs">
(Menu goes here)</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

When I just make my `#navbar` `position:fixed;` it clearly then ignores all layout formatting and expands past my website's layout. For this reason I'm trying to set the width to the page's `#wrapper`, which is set to only be a certain width of the page.

**Edited** to show header content in layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. My problem was that I was trying to figure out the top position of `#navbar`, but `#navbar` was my menu and theoretically always moving, and so the top position was always changing. What I had to do was to find the top position of `#navbar`, but then fix the position of the UL `.Nav-Tabs` inside of it. Then I realized that resizing the screen messed up the navigation so I added an event listener to change the width of the navigation as the screen resized.

**EDIT:** Oh yeah! Here's the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nLwwx31y/).

So like this:

jQuery

```
var menu = $(".nav-tabs"); /* set menu to UL, not DIV */

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var wrapperWidth = $("#wrapper").css("width");
        var menuPos = $("#navbar").offset(); /* find top of DIV */
        var menuTopPos = menuPos.top;

        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > menuTopPos ) {
            menu.css("position", "fixed");
            menu.css("top", "0px");
            menu.css("width", wrapperWidth);

        }
        else {
            menu.css("position", "relative");
            menu.css("width", "100%");
        }

    });

    // code to check menu width against wrapper width on resize
    $(window).resize(function(){

        var menuWidth = menu.css("width");
        var wrapperWidth = $("#wrapper").css("width");

        if ( menuWidth != wrapperWidth ) {
            menu.css("width", wrapperWidth);
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need any javascript to do this. If you just want the navigation to stay at the top from the beginning, just give it a `position:fixed`. Of course, this means doing all your layout work correctly.

Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLnuu2gp/) for a good example of how to accomplish this.

basically theres a parent element that's fixed, and the child element inside can be styled however you want.

generally when I build websites, I create a class called "website-width" which is the width area that I want website content to fall inside of. And inside of every section of my website, I add another div, give it this class "website-width" and put all content inside of it. This will keep all your website content in a fixed width so its consistent, and it makes it easier to extend or update than if you have one giant div with width:1000px with everything in it

***UPDATE***

[Is this](http://jsfiddle.net/hLnuu2gp/4/) what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually, what this code isn't showing is that there is a header DIV above this navigation with stuff in it. When the page loads, this navigation needs to be below this header. I'll edit my question so that's a bit more clear.

Comment: @ShirleyDodson I see, I will update my fiddle as well

Comment: @ShirleyDodson take a look at the fiddle in the update to my answer.

Comment: Yes, That is exactly what I'm trying to do. However, how do I get that to work for my navigation? Also, noticed that the header has a fixed height. That would be useful, but my header doesn't. It's dynamic, and changes height depending on the screen size. So I can't gauge height that way . . .

Comment: you can always get the height of the header on document ready and store it in a variable, and check against that in your scroll method. Id love to spend some more time looking at your example but there is too much code and I'm still at work. Try to follow my example and see if you can apply it to your code